# Quantidade de métodos por classe Java

Tags: java

Gostaria de saber se existe uma quantidade limite de métodos por classe java, se existe como devo proceder em casos onde preciso exceder o limite ?

Comment: Você refere-se na prática, em questão de memória ou limitação da linguagem, ou idealmente falando, como "boas práticas"? Mas independente disso, se sua classe começa a ter métodos em excesso, tem coisa errada e seria melhor revisar os conceitos de unidade de código e responsabilidade única.

Comment: boas praticas, tenho uma interface com uma quantidade bem expressiva, e preciso adicionar mais métodos. Neste caso, estou com receio de criar um mostro rsrs.

Comment: Pelo visto já criou... Essa interface demanda, de fato, tantos métodos assim? Todos eles são requeridos para executar a responsabilidade desta unidade? Isso não deveria ser dividido em mais classes/interfaces?

Comment: verdade, alguma dica pra arrumar essa bagunça? talvez re-organizar os métodos por classe!?

Comment: ** Isso não deveria ser dividido em mais classes/interfaces? ** acabei de pensar nisso

Comment: Para isso, só sabendo como está a classe e o que ela deveria fazer... sem o código é impossível afirmar qualquer coisa concreta. Quem sabe você consegue [edit] a pergunta e mudar para isso.

Comment: Woss, essa minha interface extends JpaRepository, então tenho vários métodos utilitários de consulta. De qualquer for vc já me ajudou, vou mover os novos métodos para uma interface especifica.

Comment: E muito disso também depende dos requisitos da aplicação. Muitas vezes lerá em diversas fontes que você não deveria fazer *tal coisa*, mas no contexto da sua aplicação pode fazer sentido, pode resolver o problema de forma mais simples e não teria porque não fazer. Nunca siga cegamente orientações; por exemplo, se alguém definir que o limite deveria ser 10 métodos, não faria sentido criar uma nova classe porque você precisa de 11 e eles são diretamente relacionados. É importante sempre entender e analisar a situação.

Comment: Não existe um número "mágico" de métodos, depende do contexto. E não é só a quantidade que conta: ter 30 métodos pequenos que fazem uma única função cada e que estão diretamente relacionados (por isso faz sentido estarem na mesma classe) pode ser melhor que 2 métodos gigantes e confusos que fazem várias coisas (e que poderiam ser quebrados em métodos menores, ou até mesmo em outras classes). Por isso não gosto dessas regras absolutas que dão números mágicos (do tipo "*não pode ter mais que X métodos/linhas/parâmetros*"), pois o contexto é mais importante (além de clareza, coesão, etc).

Comment: Regras assim podem até servir como diretrizes ou orientações gerais (se tem "muita coisa", é um alerta para rever, por exemplo), mas é importante analisar o todo, o contexto, o problema, pois podem haver situações em que faz mais sentido quebrar as regras (como disse o @Woss, se a regra for X métodos, mas fizer **total sentido** criar X + 1, vale a pena criar outra classe só pra esse método a mais, em nome da "boa prática"? eu acho que não). Boas práticas deveriam ser guias, que você só segue quando faz sentido, e não leis absolutas que você faz cegamente sem analisar o todo.

Answer (score 3):

Sim existe um limite que é imposto pela JVM do Java (Java Virtual Machine), este limite é de **65535** que é o equivalente a 2<sup>16</sup> - 1, que é o número mais alto que pode ser representado por um número binário de 16 bits sem sinal.

Não digo que é impossível você atingir esse número, só acho que é improvável, porque provavelmente você estaria fugindo das boas praticas de programação, mas se por um acaso você atinja esse limite você deve criar uma nova classe e implementar esses métodos na nova classe.